# Get plotchar() to display value in 4 decimal places, not whole number

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The following code will display USDEUR closing price as a whole number using plotchar(). I want to display the value in 4 decimal places.

`plotchar(USDEUR, title="USDEUR", char="", location=location.top, color=color.white)`

I am open to other methods such as new.label()

I am using pinescript v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use precision parameter

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", precision = 4)

plotchar(USDEUR, title="USDEUR", char="", location=location.top, color=color.white)
```